# Data Binding Applied to PathGeometry

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to render a simple image by binding a PathFigureCollection defined in Code-Behind to the Figures property of a corresponding UI element. PropertyChanged is appearing as null in the debugger and the figures I'm trying to render are not appearing.

This is my first time implementing data binding so I'm guessing the issue lies with my understanding of it. Most similar issues I've found were solved by setting the DataContext variable or setting Source instead of Path in the XAML. I implemented those solutions and they don't solve my problem.

```
 <Window x:Class="DrawingSandBox.MainWindow"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DrawingSandBox"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="754">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="700" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <mage.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
        <Image.Source>
            <DrawingImage>
                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen Thickness="11" Brush="Black"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="{Binding Path=Frame, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" /> 
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
            </DrawingImage>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image> 

</Grid>
```

```
namespace DrawingSandBox 
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static readonly CurveBuilder curve = new CurveBuilder();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = curve;
    }
}
public class CurveBuilder : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private PointCollection points;
    private PolyBezierSegment seg;
    private PathFigureCollection frame;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public PathFigure Figure;
    public PathFigureCollection Frame
    {
        get
        {
            return frame;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != frame)
            {
                frame = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Frame");
            }
        }
    }

    public CurveBuilder()
    {
        points = new PointCollection { new Point(20, 20), new Point(40, 40) };
        seg = new PolyBezierSegment(points, true);
        Figure = new PathFigure(new Point(50, 50), new PathSegmentCollection { seg }, false);
        Frame = new PathFigureCollection { Figure };
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

}
}
```

As it stands, this code merely displays a blank page.

Comment: PropertyChanged is null because you are in the constructor of your CurveBuilder class. No other element could have registered an event handler yet. If CurveBuilder is supposed to ever only create paths figures at construction time, you would not need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged at all. And you should then make the Frame property readonly.

Comment: I always implement inotifypropertychanged because (afaik) there is still the potential for memory leaks. Even if you think this class will never be a problem, it's easily overlooked in maintenance. https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/ . Why an image rather than a path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least 3 points for the `PolyBezierSegment` to show up.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.polybeziersegment?view=netframework-4.8):

> A cubic Bezier curve is defined by four points: a start point, an end point and two 
>       control points. A PolyBezierSegment specifies one or more cubic Bezier curves by 
>       setting the Points property to a collection of points. For every three points in the 
>       collection, the first and second points specify the two control points of the curve 
>       and the third point specifies the end point.

The binding is correct. Add one more `Point` to your `PointCollection` or use a `PolyQuadraticBezierSegment` or `QuadraticBezierSegment`.